# How to select element inside first-child selector jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

Here our simple code snippet of jquery, where we want to select the `p` element, but what am i writing is not correct, so help us to get them.

```
<div class="first">
  <ul class="first_ul">
    <li class="first_li">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <div class="hello"></div>
          <p class="firstP" url="hello.html">Content of First Paragrph</p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="second_li">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <div class="hello"></div>
          <p class="firstP" url="hello2.html">Content of Second Paragrph</p>
       </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here , what i am doing

`$('.fist_ul .first_li:first-child p');`

and actually we want to get the `attribute` of `p` element `url`

Thanks.

Comment: why u ve 2 nested li?? and not <ul><li></li><li></li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.first_ul .second_li p');
```

Seems there was misspell. And your code is not semantic, I mean, inside the `<li>` there is another `<li>` it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have incorect selector . it should use :

```
$('.first_ul .first_li:first-child p');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8de0aumt/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
$(".first_ul li").find('p')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```js
$('.first_ul .first_li p').attr('url'); // for only <P> of first li's url
$('.first_ul .second_li p').attr('url'); // for only <P> of second li's url

// for all the <p> you have used in all the <li>s
$('.first_ul li p').each(function(k,v){
    var wq = $(v).attr('url');
    console.log(wq);
});
```